# installing locally a symfony1 project from github

Tags: symfony1

I'm new to symfony and discovered it's quite different from rails. There is a project on github (`https://github.com/openpolis/openparlamento`) that I am trying to set up locally.

when I go to my `localhost/openparlamento-master/web/index.php` the page gives routing errors obviously. When I click on the homepage link it goes to localhost, or when I click on contact goes to localhost/contact (which doesn't exist).

I tried going into `apps/fe/config/routing.yml` (fe is my application) and tried to make changes there, but it is not working. Is there a way to automatically change all routes? I'll be thankful for a source of documentation on how to change routes on an existing symfony1 project (I didn't find any).
Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the command line in root project directory try running (hopefully you are on unix or linux):

sudo php symfony fix-perms

and then

php symfony cc

Make sure that the /web folder is you web root.  You will need to set up a local host that points to that directory.

Comment: What type of system are you on?